# Set path for js files generated by GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have GWT application and I need to use files, generated for client side in Java EE application that doesn't use GWT. Actually, I just want to include my_app.nocache.js in some html page.

This part works fine, problems begin when my_app.nocache.js tries to load other resources, generated by GWT (other *.js files and *.css files). But I have all my resources in /_resources/mypackage/ and my_app.nocache.js doesn't know anything about this and tries to load just my_name.css instead of /_resources/mypackage/my_name.css

Is there any way to set up path for GWT to generate resource files, so it wold be same, as I use in my Java application?

Comment: I've tried using this [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling#How_do_I_change_the_location_of_my_cache/nocache_HTML_files?) solution, but it didn't work for me - js files are in the same directory as before.

Comment: Why you don't want to place my_app.nocache.js into  /_resources/mypackage/ and in html code point to /_resources/mypackage/my_app.nocache.js?